# How to refresh csv data table in mySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, csv, refresh

I have a table loaded in MySQl workbench that I would like to refresh on a daily basis as the data changes.

Is there a way to refresh the data already held in SQL without having to remove the table and reload a fresh copy?

Comment: Do you mean that you have CSV file which contains the data exported from MySQL using SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE, and you want to refresh it daily? If so then the answer is NO - MySQL cannot delete existing file or rewrite it. You may either remove old file before exporting new data or export into the file which has another name (for example based on the current date).

Comment: To give more context, I have list of customers who go from live to lost on a daily basis, (new customers and those who have left) this can change on a daily basis and I need to understand the number that has joined and left. 
This comes via a refreshed CSV file from SFTP site downloaded to a folder. 
It would be useful if there was a script that replaced the current imported CSV file with the new one?

Comment: I see the next solution. You create MySQL Event procedure which exports needed data daily using unique filename. You create a task in OS which detects that new file is created in the directory, waits a little (until exporting finished with guarantee), then removes old CSV and renames new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the table every day in MySQL Workbench you can create an event.
Something like this

```sql
CREATE EVENT test_event_03
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
DO
   INSERT INTO messages(message,created_at)
   VALUES('Test MySQL recurring Event',NOW());
```

From [Source](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/)

Comment: OP needs export data (not insert into the table) on daily (not every-minute) basis.

Comment: I think the question leaves a lot to be interpreted. What made me think he'd be dealing with SQL was "I have a table loaded in MySQl workbench".

Comment: See OP's comment to the question.

Comment: The every-minute example was just taken from the source. Its not a solution, just a suggestion as to how he could approach what I thought the issue was.